Rails 7.0.8 application is not parsing turbo_stream but downloads the file
I have built a very simple test application (https://github.com/Chrisgo-75/rls7_docker_test_app/tree/main) that demonstrates the issue I am seeing on my production app. I have ruined my production app in trying to unsuccessfully get turbo to work.
The issue is that Rails 7 application is not parsing the turbo_stream request but instead downloads the file app/views/posts/create.turbo_stream.erb. When I try to create a new post is when the app downloads the turbo_stream file. With Rails 7 I thought Turbo should work out-of-the-box?
Any suggestions on how to get turbo_streams to work?
Thank you
Chris

It does work fine. Make sure you understand that turbo_streams are for updating your current page and you're not using the turbo_stream.append helper correctly:
<!-- app/views/posts/index.html.erb -->

<div id="post_form">
  <%= render "form", post: Post.new %>
</div>

<!-- `id="posts"` will be the target of the turbo stream -->
<div id="posts">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= render post %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Show this post", post %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>

Do not add turbo_stream url extension:
# app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

<%# form_with(model: post, format: :turbo_stream) do |form| %>

<%= form_with model: post do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>

# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: [
          # `id` target        vvvvv
          turbo_stream.append(:posts, @post),
          # reset form
          turbo_stream.update(:post_form, partial: "form", locals: {post: Post.new}),
        ]
      end
      format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully created." }
    else
      format.turbo_stream do
        # render errors
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(:post_form, partial: "form", locals: {post: @post})
      end
      format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


Thank you for your answer but I have another question. If the Posts Index page now shows both the "Create Post" form and lists posts, if I create a new post shouldn't the Index page get updated with new Post? Versus with your modifications after creating a new post the show.html.erb page is being displayed. My code has been updated per your example in Git repo.

When I create a new Post the console says the HTTP request is HTML Processing by PostsController#create as HTML. Shouldn't it be something along the lines of a turbo_stream HTTP request?

works fine for me. are you running bin/dev? since you're using jsbundling-rails. "shouldn't the Index page get updated" - yes that's how it supposed to work. check for any js errors in browser console, type Turbo to see if turbo is loaded.

so I wasn't compiling assets. I had it commented out in the entrypoints file. Thank you for working with me in getting this working.
